# how make a searchbox with materialize where the search button stay in same line?

Tags: css, materialize

In my sample, the button show in down.

[image]

```
<form id="search-site"  action='search' method='get'>
<div class="input-field">
<input id="search" type="search" name='q'>
<label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons" >search</i></label></div>
<button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code
HTML

```
<div class="container">
<form id="search-site"  action='search' method='get'>
  <div class="input-group">
<div class="input-field">
<input id="search" type="search" name='q'>
<label class="label-icon" for="search">
  <i class="material-icons" >search</i>
 </label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="input-group-addon btn">search</button>
</div>

</form>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.input-group{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.input-group .input-field,
.input-group .input-group-addon{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

hope this helps..